# Как сделать подготовленный запрос

Tags: php, pdo

Здраствуйте! У меня есть такой код

```
<?php $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT film_name, film_small_img FROM new_film"); ?>
<?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
<a href="films/<?php echo $row['film_name']; ?>.php">
  <img src="<?php echo $row['film_small_img']; ?>" alt="" style="width: 100px;">
  <p><?php echo $row['film_name']; ?></p>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Как мне сделать такой же запрос, но через подготовленные выражения?

Comment: В данном запросе использовать подготовленные выражения __не имеет смысла__

Answer (score 0):

Пример для INSERT INTO:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `chat`(`userid`, `message`, `datetime`) VALUES (:userid,:message,NOW())');
$arr = [
    "message" => $message,
    "userid" => $userid,
];
$stmt->execute($arr);
```

Подготавливается выражение, создается ассоциативный массив, ключами которого являются переменные в подготовленном запросе, запрос "экзекьютится".

Если нужно получить строки, например если это Select *... можно выполнить `$stmt -> fetchAll()`